# Why the dangling pointer shows the value and address even after freeing it using free function?

Tags: c

In the following program a pointer has been freed using the `free()` function but still it prints the address and value of the initialized variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int a = 1;

    int *a_ptr = (int *)malloc((sizeof(int)));

    a_ptr = &a;

    printf("The address of 'a' is %p\n", a_ptr);

    free(a_ptr); // A dangling pointer

    printf("The address of 'a' is %p\n", a_ptr);

    printf("The value of 'a' is %d", *a_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to access the memory after you've freed it.  Anything can happen — crashes, garbage, the same answer you got before you released the memory; they're all valid responses to undefined behaviour.

Comment: You tagged a bunch of junk here including C++ and random compilers. Please specify **only** what is relevant.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: *Use-after-free* bug. Undefined behaviour. Anything can happen, including the old data sticking around. Additionally, this allocates, throws the allocation into the sun when replacing it with the address of a local variable, and then tries to free a local variable, which was never dynamically allocated. In short, this code is just chock full of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading something, the line `a_ptr = &a;` leaks the allocated memory.  The line `free(a_ptr);` attempts to free memory that was not allocated.  As a general rule, my first comment applies, but not really to the code in the question.  There are other problems instead.

Comment: you need to use `*a_ptr = a;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line of code:

```
a_ptr = &a;
```

The pointer `a_ptr` no longer points to the memory allocated by `malloc()`. You then call `free()` with the value of `a_ptr` being the address of `a`. Then the following lines of code:

```
printf("The address of 'a' is %p\n", a_ptr);

printf("The value of 'a' is %d", *a_ptr);
```

print the address of `a` and the value of `a` consecutively. You invoked undefined behavior with the call to `free()` and the memory you allocated remained unchanged..it was not actually freed.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code has 3 instances of undefined behavior:

- **[minor]** `printf("The address of 'a' is %p\n", a_ptr)`: you pass a pointer to `int` where `printf` expects a pointer to `void`. You should cast the argument as `(void *)a_ptr`.
- **[major]** `free(a_ptr)`: `a_ptr` was changed to point to `a`, a variable with automatic storage (`a_ptr = &a`).  Calling `free` with a pointer that does not point to an allocated block nor is a null pointer has undefined behavior.
- **[minor]** `printf("The address of 'a' is %p\n", a_ptr)`: you pass a pointer to `int` where `printf` expects a pointer to `void`. You should cast the argument as `(void *)a_ptr`.  This is the same problem as the first one, but if `a_ptr` still pointed to the original allocated block and had been freed, merely passing its value to `printf` has undefined behavior.

Note that `free` does not change the value of `a_ptr` so it is expected that both calls to `printf` produce the same output. `free` only changes the internal data of the allocation system to account for the block being freed. Reading from the pointer after the call to `free` has undefined behavior as the memory may have been unmapped hence is no longer accessible. On some ancient systems, merely evaluating the value of the pointer may cause problems.  The only safe thing to do with the pointer after freeing it is setting it to `NULL` or storing the address of another object into it.

Comment: If the pointer changed it's pointing memory after assigning 'a' then why it shows the same memory address before and after freeing the memory? Can you give an example program of dangling pointer?

Comment: @user10897549: after `free(a_ptr)`, `a_ptr` does not change but it is now an invalid pointer, an example of [*dangling pointer*](https://www.scaler.com/topics/c/dangling-pointer-in-c/) albeit this term is not used in the C Standard. Its value has not changed so `printf("%p", (void *)a_ptr)` produces the same output, but the memory it points to may be used for something else or may have become inaccessible, so reading from it has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `free` function takes a `void *` parameter. It can't change the pointer you pass into it.

So it does free the memory, but it cannot change the pointer itself. To change the passed pointer function, it has to take a pointer to the pointer.

If you want to assign NULL to the pointer you need to define a function like this:

```
void myfree(void *p)  // To avoid warnings and void pointer can be converted to any other type of pointers
{
    void **ptr = p;
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(*ptr));

    printf("Before myfree: %p\n", (void *)ptr);

    myfree(&ptr);
    printf("After myfree: %p\n", (void *)ptr);
}
```

[Code at *Compiler Explorer*](https://godbolt.org/z/fhf8K6xPn).

Comment: Read the code. OP’s code does not free dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: your code doesn't show the address of a dangling pointer after freeing it's memory but only shows the NULL address.

You code can be simplified as followws.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(*ptr));

   printf("Before myfree: %p\n", ptr);

   ptr = NULL;

   printf("After myfree: %p\n", ptr);
}

Comment: @user10897549 you did not read the answer but you commented. Sweet. And your code example makes no sense in the answer scope.

Comment: But what is the use of free() function if we can assign NULL value directly to a pointer?

Comment: But why do we need free() if "NULL" assignment can also fee the pointer. How can you be use that the free() function has freed the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Myfree() funciton:

```
void myfree(void *p) {
    void **ptr = p;
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL; }
```

we can use the following lines of code also:

```
int a = 1, *a_ptr;

void *a_ptr = (void *)malloc((sizeof(int)));

a_ptr = &a;

free(a_ptr);
```

*ptr = NULL;

The above code will also work the same way but why we need to use the free() function if "NULL" assignment can also free the memory?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).